# Close file after write file in R

Tags: r, file

In other languages, when you write data into a file, you have to close the file. 
I find in R you need not close a file after you write data into it, am I correct?
What happens if I write:

```
require(quantmod)  
getSymbols("GS")  
write(GS,'test')
```

Comment: It depends how you write to the file. Can you post the code you are using?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to close the file, because `write()` closes it for you:

```
> write
function (x, file = "data", ncolumns = if (is.character(x)) 1 else 5, 
    append = FALSE, sep = " ") 
# Using cat() function
cat(x, file = file, sep = c(rep.int(sep, ncolumns - 1), "\n"),
    append = append)
<bytecode: 0x053fdb10>
<environment: namespace:base>

> cat
function (..., file = "", sep = " ", fill = FALSE, labels = NULL, 
    append = FALSE) 
{
    if (is.character(file)) 
        if (file == "") 
            file <- stdout()
        else if (substring(file, 1L, 1L) == "|") {
            file <- pipe(substring(file, 2L), "w")
            # Closing here
            on.exit(close(file))
        }
        else {
            file <- file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w"))
            # Or here
            on.exit(close(file))
        }
    .Internal(cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append))
}
<bytecode: 0x053fdd68>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Comment: Let's clarify that this is the behavior when the `file` argument to `write` or `cat` is a character, where it is interpreted as a filename (here `'test'`). If instead the file had been opened through a file connection: `filehandle <- file('test')` and passed to `write(GS, filehandle)`, then it is recommended to later close the filehandle with `close(filehandle)`.

Comment: @flodel I think your comment is worthy of an answer, because the situation is quite a bit more complex, as you point out.